# Why does window.onerror not catch stack overflow errors in IE9?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, internet-explorer-9, stack-overflow

I'm using `window.onerror` to catch and log client-side errors. I've read about the various caveats to this approach, but I haven't been able to track down any info on this particular case.

For some reason IE9 does not seem to catch stack overflow exceptions. The below example catches both errors when run in Chrome and Firefox as well as if I use devtools in IE9 and set browser mode to IE8 or IE7. However, when run in IE9 mode, it only catches the `'test' is undefined` exception, but ignore the stack overflow exception.

I have put together a simple example, to demonstrate this:

```
window.onerror = errorHandler;

function errorHandler (msg) {
    alert(msg);        
}

setTimeout(function () {
    test.test = "test";
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function stackoverflow() {
    stackoverflow();
}, 2000);
​
```

Here is a working example as well: http://jsfiddle.net/Mzvbk/1/

Can anyone shed some light on why this is?

**Update August 29, 2012**

I posted this question on the [Internet Explorer Developer Center](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/bf3cf56b-b5cd-4985-ad61-534f8b2a8b9f) as well, but so far it hasn't given me much.

At this point, the best guess (as suggested by @RyanKinal in his comment) is that since the call stack size is exceeded, there is no room to put the call to the error handler on the stack.

I still like to believe that error handling is handled separately from the normal stack, as it seem to be in other browser (even older versions of IE), but if that isn't the case, it would be nice to see a reference, bug-report or statement of some kind, indicating that this actually is the case with IE9.

**Update September 5, 2012**

As described by Ren and Vega in their comments, Firefox 15 sometimes (seemingly random) seem to swallow that exception as well.

Comment: I really hope this isn't the reason, but it would be kind of hilarious if, since the call stack size was exceeded, IE couldn't call the handler.

Comment: @RyanKinal LOL, I didn't even think of that. It would be awful if that is the case.

Comment: stack error is not thrown on FF 15. Just seeing the **ReferenceError: test is not defined**.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried disabling script debugging on the browser?

> A common problem that bites many developers occurs when their onerror
>   handler is not called because they have script debugging enabled for
>   Internet Explorer. This will be the case by default if you have
>   installed the Microsoft Script Debugger or Microsoft Visual Studio
>   6.0® (specifically Visual InterDev 6.0™)—onerror handling is how these products launch their debugger.

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms976144.aspx) (includes details on how to disable it).

---

Additional information following up on the comments:

Then I wonder is it related to this:

> Internet Explorer 9 is compiled with the new C++ compiler provided
>   with Visual Studio 2010. This compiler includes a feature known as
>   Enhanced GS aka Stack Buffer Overrun Detection, which helps prevent
>   stack buffer overruns by detecting stack corruption and **avoiding**
>   execution if such corruption is encountered.

([Source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/03/07/internet-explorer-9-security-part-1-enhanced-memory-protections.aspx))

Sounds like it could be that it is stopping before the overflow as a protection mechanism?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have indeed disabled script debugging, and `window.onerror` catch exceptions and call my custom error handler for all but stack overflow errors.

Comment: That does indeed sound like a possible reason, thanks for the reference. My example does however throw a `Out of stack space` exception to the console, so it doesn't seem to prevent it all together, or at least it is trying to alert the fact that such an exception would occur. In that case, it would have been nice if it was to throw a catchable exception as well.

Comment: I seen that in the console yeah. It could be that it throws that error up when it detects that the error is about to occur and then stops execution. I would have hoped that they would have checked to see if the exception was expected and caught before stopping script execution though. Indeed, it is still unclear whether this is what is happening. I am just speculating here. I just noticed that the code you posted doesn't always throw up the stack trace error on FF 15 so it may be something else altogether?

Comment: @christofer - Just some additional detail on FF15. It swallows the error most of the time it would seem but I have had an alert from Firefox saying 'Too much recursion' a couple of times when running the script as well.

Comment: Thats odd, are you running the same code every time, or have you altered it to cause the alert?

Comment: Just refreshing the page. If I attempt to open Firebug and then refresh, the whole browser crashes also. I took a screenshot: http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/7528/recursion.jpg

Comment: Experiencing the same thing, the alert is shown perhaps 1 out of every 10 refreshes or so.